# Normal ordering in 2D thermal CFT

Tags: renormalization, conformal-field-theory, singularities, regularization, thermal-field-theory

I am trying to understand the notion of normal ordering in thermal CFT in 2D CFT, for instance I consider a two-point function of scalar primary operator with $\Delta$ dimension at finite temperature $\beta$, which is given by conformally mapping the two point function from complex plane to a cylinder, and I get 
$$ \langle \mathcal{O}(x) \mathcal{O} \rangle_\beta = \left(\dfrac{\pi}{\beta \sinh(\frac{\pi x}{\beta})}\right)^{2\Delta}.$$ Now I do a small-$x$ expansion of the above term, I always have a divergence of $\frac{1}{x}^{2 \Delta}$ sitting in front of the expansion, so I was wondering what is the notion of normal ordering, in order to apply fluctuation-dissipation theorem in thermal CFTs?